# Trying to convert dataframe to rdd for RankingMetrics

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The datasets consists of two csv files that include movie details and then user rankings of those movies. What I've attempted to do is combine the movie rankings for each user with the details of each movie. Then I converted it to an RDD so that it can be passed to the function RankingMetrics. The goal is to get the Mean Average Precision and print out the top 5 suggested movies for the user I have created.

movies.csv looks like

```
movieId,title,genres
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
6,Heat (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
7,Sabrina (1995),Comedy|Romance
8,Tom and Huck (1995),Adventure|Children
9,Sudden Death (1995),Action
```

and ratings.csv looks like

```
userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
1,2,3.5,1112486027
1,29,3.5,1112484676
1,32,3.5,1112484819
1,47,3.5,1112484727
1,50,3.5,1112484580
1,112,3.5,1094785740
1,151,4.0,1094785734
1,223,4.0,1112485573
1,253,4.0,1112484940
```

What I'm trying to do is take a DataFrame I created, convert it to an RDD, then pass that RDD to RankingMetrics.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
ratings_data = spark.read.option("inferSchema", True).option("header", True).csv("/home/hadoop/assignment4/ml-20m/ratings.csv").drop("timestamp")


movies_data = spark.read.option("inferSchema", True).option("header", True).csv("/home/hadoop/assignment4/ml-20m/movies.csv")

data = ratings_data.join(movies_data, ratings_data.movieId == movies_data.movieId).drop(movies_data.movieId)




columns = ['userId', 'movieId', 'rating']
vals = [(0,1,4.0), 
    (0,2,3.0),
    (0,3,3.0),
    (0,4,4.0),
    (0,5,4.0),
    (0,6,1.0),
    (0,7,1.0),
    (0,8,3.0), 
    (0,9,5.0),
    (0,10,4.0),
    (0,11,3.5),
    (0,12,3.6),
    (0,13,3.4),
    (0,14,3.5),
    (0,15,3.0),
    (0,16,2.0),
    (0,17,4.0),
    (0,18,2.0),
    (0,19,1.0),
    (0,20,3.0)
    ]

new_ratings = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)


new_ratings = new_ratings.join(movies_data, new_ratings.movieId == movies_data.movieId).drop(movies_data.movieId)


data = data.union(new_ratings)


train,test= data.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])

als = ALS(userCol="userId", itemCol="movieId", ratingCol="rating", coldStartStrategy="drop", nonnegative=True)


param_grid = ParamGridBuilder()\
        .addGrid(als.rank, [12])\
        .addGrid(als.maxIter, [18])\
        .addGrid(als.regParam, [.17])\
        .build()


evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="mse", labelCol="rating", predictionCol="prediction")
tvs = CrossValidator(estimator=als, estimatorParamMaps=param_grid, evaluator=evaluator, numFolds=3)
model = tvs.fit(train)
best_model=model.bestModel

predictions = best_model.transform(test).rdd

metrics = RankingMetrics(predictions)

print(metrics.meanAvergePrecision())
```

However when I run this code I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
```

Answer (score 0):

May it will apply easily in spark 3.0.0.
Spark ml (not mllib) evaluate method of RankingMetrics can set parameter Dataset(not RDD).

```
override def evaluate(dataset: Dataset[_]): Double
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/RankingEvaluator.scala

now spark 3.0.0 has been released in preview version.

https://spark.apache.org/news/spark-3.0.0-preview.html

in pyspark

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/ml/evaluation.py

refer to 762~867 line